# Count occurences of strings in a fileusing grep or sed?

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file like this:

```
[10/May/2012:00:00:03 +0000]
[10/May/2012:00:00:03 +0000]
[10/May/2012:00:00:03 +0000]
[10/May/2012:00:00:03 +0000]
[10/May/2012:00:00:06 +0000]
[10/May/2012:00:00:06 +0000]
...
```

I wish to generate a CSV file which counts the number of occurences of each date time.

e.g.

```
[10/May/2012:00:00:03 +0000], 4
[10/May/2012:00:00:06 +0000], 2
...
```

Is it possible to do this using sed or grep or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 sort inputFile | uniq -c | awk '{print $2", "$1}'
```

or

```
 sort inputFile | uniq -c | sed 's;^\s*\([0-9]*\)\s*\(.*\)$;\2, \1;'
```

Comment: Thanks Prince. Can you provide full command, just slightly confused with the ... Thanks.

Comment: That gives: awk: '{print
awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
uniq: write error.  I am using gnu awk on windows and sort from cygwin.

Comment: @dublintech: It maybe a carriage return issue. Try sed command otherwise

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about sed because you don't have hash tables in sed, but you can do it with a perl one liner...

```
perl -e 'while (<>) {chomp; $a{$_}++}; for $k (keys %a) { print "$k $a{$k}\n"; }' file.txt
```

Comment: @WilliamPursell That's seriously petty

Comment: To further elaborate:  perl's readline operator (<>) does a great job handling ARGV files, and it is a dis-service to the world to perpetuate the practice of not using it.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Can you elaborate?  I'm not aware of how you could do that without calling `open` or `-n` which of course wouldn't work in this case.  Or using `<` from the shell I guess.

Comment: Your solution looks good, just write: perl -e ... file.txt  By passing the filename as an argument, <> will read the file.  There is this bizarre myth that <> only reads stdin, but it does much more than that.

Comment: Thanks for comments. But trying to do without perl install.

Answer (score 0):

That's the job well handled by awk. It can all be done in 1 line awk like this:

```
awk '{ts[$0]++;} END{for (var in ts) print var",", ts[var];}' file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
[10/May/2012:00:00:03 +0000], 4
[10/May/2012:00:00:06 +0000], 2
```